# Chart.js - Moment.js could not be found! You must include it before Chart.js to use the time scale

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, chart.js

I am trying to display a chart that shows data for the past 30 days. The chart works when it is run with my webpack development server. However it fails when I build it (npm run build). The error it produces is:

> ("Chart.js - Moment.js could not be found! You must include it before
>   Chart.js to use the time scale. Download at https://momentjs.com")

I have checked every possible solution I could find on Google and none of them seem to fix the issue. I've included moment.js as requested, but that throws a ton of new errors, chief among them being window is not defined in moment.js. I should also note, that when I inspect the element in the browser, this error shows:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://internal-server:5000/api/service_info/tt?severity=2.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I don't think this is the cause because I am successfully making GET requests to other API's on the backend and they do not throw this error. More importantly, CORS is enabled. The relevant piece of code is included below.

Thanks,

```
let ctx = document.getElementById("canvas");
        this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: all_dates,
            datasets: [
              {
                data: cummulative_sums,
                borderColor: '#3cba9f',
                fill: false,
                label: 'Failures in past 30 days'
              },
              {
                data: comparison_cummulative_sums,
                borderColor: '#ce5fc3',
                fill: false,
                label: 'Failures 30 days prior'
              }
            ]
          },
          options: {
            legend: {
              display: true
            },
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                display: true
              }],
              yAxes: [{
                display: true
              }],
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: is there a fiddle?

Comment: @stack-flo : i had a similar issue, and i remember adding `momentjs` explicitly via yarn/npm and save it to dev_Dependencies. try building once added.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal unfortunately this is an intranet application and so much of the code is not going to work in Fiddle including this chart.

Comment: Since your question is about `momentjs` not being found you need to show us how you added your scripts, especially `momentjs`

Comment: Also looks like there are two issues here: 1. with momentjs dependency missing or not added 2. CORS issue with your api. please do not mix up the two. try with dummy data possibly first. and resolve the next

Comment: @BShaps I included momentjs like so: import * as moment from moment

Comment: @Jaya I addressed the CORS issue in my post. I said I do not believe that is the issue as I am making API calls to other services on the same site within this same AngularJS app and they do not throw a CORS error.

Comment: If that is the case why even mention the cors issue here ? not sure i understand.. all the errors listed on your console may or may not be related, that said, did you try adding the momentjs as mentioned by me in my previous comment - please share your package.json to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

The Chart.js has the following two versions:

**Stand-Alone Build**

Files:

```
dist/Chart.js
dist/Chart.min.js
```

**Bundled Build**

Files:

```
dist/Chart.bundle.js
dist/Chart.bundle.min.js
```

The Stand-Alone Build does not include moment.js and you have to include it but the Bundled Build includes the moment.js.

Adding the bundled version will include and fix the problem:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note: Since chart.js 2.8 there is no "bundle" version anymore. This solution does not work anymore when using the latest chart.js version

Answer (score 1):

One way of getting around the CORS problem is requesting the data to the client side as padded JSON. Here is an npm package to do so: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-jsonp

It will return your data as a promise and then you just have to call .json() on it to get back JSON without padding:

```
fetchJsonp('http://internal-address:5000/api/service_info/tt?severity=2')
.then(data => data.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Sounds like that might be a bandaid, but it could get you unstuck for now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `yarn add` instead of `npm install`. Your issue reminds me of a similar one I had that was likely solved this way IIRC.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can delete package-lock.json and do a npm install again, then build again and see if the problem still exists.